# How does Redis perform at peak load?

Tags: redis

Can't seem to find an answer and benchmarks are really tale-telling.

How does Redis handle itself during peak load/usage?

The question comes from knowing CPU usage may hit 100% of its logical core, or memory may be over used.

What happens in these cases?

Comment: This leads up to, if I wanted one Redis instance to handle 10K users and that's overloading the machine could I handle 20K users with added delay and maintain parallel processing.

Comment: I'm also interested about this but you should learn about redis cluster if you want more I/O out of a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Redis isn't CPU heavy, and will act like any other application when CPU usage is high, but this largely depends on your Redis version.

Prior to Redis 4.0, it was entirely single-threaded, and long running operations would block (like background saves, DEL's with large objects, etc.) Since 4.0, most of these types of operations are pushed to the background. With saves to disk with the `bgsave` command, Redis now forks itself and does the save in the child, leaving the parent open to accept changes. 6.0 changed a few things like the `del` command now acts as `unlink`, and pushes the actual delete to a thread. There were some plans to add more multi-threading to Redis version 7.0, but it appears this was pushed to 7.2.

The biggest concern however is reaching max system memory, or the `maxmemory` directive in Redis' config. When this happens, Redis' eviction policy comes into play (set by the `maxmemory-policy` directive).

Here are the available eviction policies and what they do:

- `noeviction`: New values aren’t saved when memory limit is reached. When a database uses replication, this applies to the primary database
- `allkeys-lru`: Keeps most recently used keys; removes least recently used (LRU) keys
- `allkeys-lfu`: Keeps frequently used keys; removes least frequently used (LFU) keys
- `volatile-lru`: Removes least recently used keys with the expire field set to true.
- `volatile-lfu`: Removes least frequently used keys with the expire field set to true.
- `allkeys-random`: Randomly removes keys to make space for the new data added.
- `volatile-random`: Randomly removes keys with expire field set to true.
- `volatile-ttl`: Removes least frequently used keys with expire field set to true and the shortest remaining time-to-live (TTL) value.

The default `maxmemory-policy` is `noeviction` from Redis version 3.0 up through 7.0. In version 2.8 and earlier, the default is `volatile-lru`.

You can read the [Key Eviction docs](https://redis.io/docs/manual/eviction/) for more.

Comment: I think @BGPHiJACK was asking about how redis handles CPU peak load. I'm also interested, could you develop the part where you say 'Redis [...] will act like any other application when CPU usage is high' please ? I mean, max memory is a thing, pretty well documented, but CPU not that much

Comment: Say CPU is at 100% and I have 20K requests <1 second. Would 40K requests equate to >1 second at these loads (just take longer to complete). That'd certainly answer all my questions the memory policy is a nice touch! (Just overall wanting to know how max-load affects the environment maybe scenarios)

Comment: Just edited my answer to add some history regarding single threaded Redis in 4.0 and what they've changed through 7.0 and upcoming 7.2. In general however, if you're experiencing high CPU due to Redis, you can look into Redis Cluster, which will shard your dataset so that each master in the cluster is only responsible for a subset of the entire data, potentially decreasing both CPU and memory usage.